# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.FileInfo' to 'System.IO.FileInfo[]

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm getting an error in the `where` clause in the below code. The error states:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.FileInfo' to 'System.IO.FileInfo[]

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get every file in the directory after or between a specific date. Then I need to loop through each file and get some information about the file.

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(dirtxt.Text);
FileInfo[] fls = info.GetFiles()
                     .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now)
                     .First();

foreach (FileInfo fi in fls)
{
    //Collect file information here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  are using `First()` so this should be :

```
FileInfo fls = info.GetFiles()
                .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now).First();
```

or with out using `First()`

```
FileInfo[] fls = info.GetFiles()
                    .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now).ToArray();
```

or my preferred method dont specify a type and use `IEnumerable`

```
var fls = info.GetFiles().Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Just as an aside, `First()` can accept a predicate so you can just use it without a `Where` clause:  `FileInfo fls = info.GetFiles().First(file => file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `First()` for single selection but trying to insert it in an array which is wrong. Try to make the query either array or a list or IEnumerable for iteration.

```
FileInfo[] fls = info.GetFiles()
    .Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now).ToArray();
```

or

```
List<FileInfo> fls = info.GetFiles()
    .Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> fls = info.GetFiles()
    .Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the First() function. This will only return the first FileInfo matching the Where clause.

Remove the .First()to get an enummerable.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to using `First()`, that will return only a single item *(or throw exception if none is found)*. You can simply remove that:

```
var fls = info.GetFiles()
    .Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= DateTime.Now);

foreach (FileInfo fi in fls)
//....
```

You don't have to get array of list back as you are going to iterate the collection in `foreach` loop.